# Multilanguage Page not working in English

Tags: php, multilingual

I am working on a PHP "multilenguage" page, and it seems to work perfectly fine on Spanish, but I asked a friend (from Netherlands) to check it out and it doesn't seem to work cause one of the selection boxes is disabled, and I don't have this problem viewing it from my computer, installed in Spanish.
I just wanted to know if there is anyone else is experimenting the same problem cause I can't really test it out any other way (proxys wont work).
[This is the page I am refering.](http://www.fenixflame.net/Signatures.php)

This is [how the page should look like](http://fenixflame.net/Images/howitshouldlooklike.png) (except it should probably be in English instead of Spanish).

Comment: They pretty look much the same to me...Are you sure is it a problem connected to languages and not browsers?

Comment: omg you are right, i just tryed with internet explorer and it doesn't work, now I wonder how can i fix it... Guess i'll have to post the code for that, hold on

Comment: Look my answer below here, take the <select> outside the <label> tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's an IE issues. In FIrefox it works fine, but with IE (8) I don't see the first select, the one I'm posting here. 
(your code:)

```
 <p>
       Background:<label>
          <select name="BGMenu" id="BGMenu">

            <option value="1">Ancient cavers</option>
            <option value="2">Black</option>
            <option value="13">Camelot Sq Table</option>
            <!-- etc. -->
            <option value="10">Zanaris</option>
          </select>
        </label>
```

Solution? take the `<select`> OUTSIDE the LABEL TAG!! Like this:

```
 <p><label for="BGmenu">Background:</label>
      <select name="BGMenu" id="BGMenu">

        <option value="1">Ancient cavers</option>
        <option value="2">Black</option>
        <option value="13">Camelot Sq Table</option>
        <!-- etc. -->
        <option value="10">Zanaris</option>
      </select>
 </p>
```

Comment: should I remove the label tag completly?

Comment: @Dangerosking Updated my answer using <label>

Comment: @Dangerosking Glad to hear that! btw, if the answer satisfies you, you may want to mark the answer as 'accepted'. Gracias ;)

Answer (score 1):

"Multilanguage" and "The Netherlands", other than that all boxes on the page you're referring are working just fine.

Comment: does it look like the image i just posted?